# Problema al recuperar vista guardada en fichero

Tags: ios, swift2, swift3

He hecho el siguiente ejemplo en el que creo un boton,le añado una funcion para el evento touch up y lo salvo en fichero.El problema es que al recuperar el boton desde el fichero ,este ya no responde al touch up .Podria añadirselo luego de cargarlo ,pero las vistas guardadas en fichero pueden ser varias y de diferente tipo ,y seria un poco engorroso añadir los eventos segun el tipo de vista.He probado creando el boton desde el storyboard en vez de programaticamente pero el resultado es el mismo.A ver si alguien me indica que me estoy dejando o si esto es asi :

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let b = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 50, height: 50))
    b.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue;b.tag = -100
    b.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.buttonClick(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    view.addSubview(b)
  }
  @IBAction func load(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let path = dataFilePath("file")
    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: path) {
      if let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: path) {
        let unarchiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWith: data as Data)
        if let button = unarchiver.decodeObject(forKey: "button") as? UIButton {
          print("button cargado")
          unarchiver.finishDecoding()
          view.addSubview(button)
        }
      }
    }
  }
  @IBAction func save(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let button = view.viewWithTag(-100)
    let data = NSMutableData()
    let archiver = NSKeyedArchiver(forWritingWith: data)
    archiver.encode(button, forKey: "button")
    archiver.finishEncoding()
    data.write(toFile: dataFilePath("file"), atomically: true)
    button?.removeFromSuperview()
  }
  func buttonClick(_ sender: UIButton){
    print("Tap")
  }
  func documentsDirectory() -> String {
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
    return paths[0]
  }
  func dataFilePath(_ name: String) -> String {
    return (documentsDirectory() as NSString).appendingPathComponent(name) as String
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Podria añadirselo luego de cargarlo ,pero las vistas guardadas en fichero pueden ser varias y de diferente tipo ,y seria un poco engorroso añadir los eventos segun el tipo de vista.

Eso es exactamente lo que tienes que hacer, debido a que las acciones no son almacenadas cuando serializas los botones.

Si tienes demasiados botones, lo que deberías hacer es asignarle un valor a la variable `tag` de cada botón antes de guardarlo en el archivo.

```
button.tag = 0 // 1,2,3,4...n
```

Entonces al momento de cargar cada botón desde el archivo, le asignas el mismo método usando

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.buttonClick(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Finalmente en `buttonClick` ejecutas la acción dependiendo del tag del botón

```
func buttonClick(_ sender: UIButton){
     print("Tap")

    if sender.tag == 0
    {
         //Ejecutar acción
    }
}
```

Comment: Lo doy por bueno si no tengo alternativa ,pero me parece una cagada.Tiene poco sentido que se pueda serializar un objeto pero no conserve toda su funcionalidad....